# Android app using inflater gets null when using findViewByID

Tags: java, android, crash, nullpointerexception, viewpagerindicator

I am working on my first Android app. When I added a functionality to save and load objects and settings on OnCreate and onRestart the app started crashing on start up.

Here is the code I made for setting things

```
public void setSettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 0);
    newGame = settings.getBoolean("newGame", true);
    autoDecide = settings.getBoolean("autoDecide", true);
    saved = settings.getBoolean("saved", false);

    if (saved) {
        player1 = readPlayer("Player 1");
        player2 = readPlayer("Player 2");
        if (player1 != null && player2 != null) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player1name)).setText("" + player1.name);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player2name)).setText("" + player2.name);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1wins)).setText("" + player1.totalWins);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2wins)).setText("" + player2.totalWins);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player1life)).setText("" + player1.life);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player2life)).setText("" + player2.life);
        }

    }
```

The NullPointerException the logCat shows points to the first findViewByID(R.id.Player1name). I tried just passing in a normal String and still got a nullPointer, so I know its the findViewById.

Here is the OnCreate that calls it

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter= new ViewPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    setSettings();

}
```

My App uses the ViewPagerIndicator, so can it someone not find it because of that?

Here is the main part of the code uses the ViewPager and switches the views.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider{
private static String[] titles = new String[]{"Settings", "2 Players"};

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titles.length;
}
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resID = 0;
    switch (position){
    case 0:
        resID = R.layout.settings;
        break;
    case 1:
        resID = R.layout.two_player;
        break;
    }
    View view = inflator.inflate(resID, null);
    ((ViewPager)collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
```

Here is the layout that it should be on when first created.

```
### Layout XML ###
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Player1name"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/player1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Player2name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight = "34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/player2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Player1life"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Player1name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Player1name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/player1life"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="28sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Player2life"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/player1add"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Player2name"
        android:text="@string/player2life"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="28sp" />        

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/player1add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Player1life"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p1add1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1add1000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1add1000"
                android:text="@string/add1000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1add500"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1add500"
                android:text="@string/add500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p1add2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1add100"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1add100"
                android:text="@string/add100" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1add50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1add50"
                android:text="@string/add50" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/player2add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/player1add"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_marginRight = "15dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p2add1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2add1000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2add1000"
                android:text="@string/add1000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2add500"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2add500"
                android:text="@string/add500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p2add2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2add100"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2add100"
                android:text="@string/add100" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2add50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2add50"
                android:text="@string/add50" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/player1sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/player1add"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p1sub1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1sub1000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1sub1000"
                android:text="@string/sub1000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1sub500"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1sub500"
                android:text="@string/sub500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p1sub2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1sub100"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1sub100"
                android:text="@string/sub100" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player1sub50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player1sub50"
                android:text="@string/sub50" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/player2sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/player1sub"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_marginRight =  "15dp">


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p2sub1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2sub1000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2sub1000"
                android:text="@string/sub1000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2sub500"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2sub500"
                android:text="@string/sub500" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/p2sub2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2sub100"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2sub100"
                android:text="@string/sub100" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/player2sub50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Player2sub50"
                android:text="@string/sub50" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/player1sub"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="@string/reset" />
```

I checked around but I did set the setContentView and I tried cleaning the project so I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Which layout is `R.id.Player1name` defined in? Unless it's in the layout that is currently being used for the activity, it won't fnd it because it looks for children of that layout. For example, if it's within `R.layout.settings`, you could use `view.findViewById(R.id.Player1name)` after inflating `view` in your switch, assuming case 0.

Comment: what does Your activity(first class) extends? Activity class OR ListActivity class?

Comment: @omidnazifi I extend Activity

Comment: try restarting eclipse and the emulator. These things might be screwing things up. That how i normally get things solved when im sure there is no error in the code.

Comment: @blessenm this is a problem I've been trying to fix for a few weeks, I have restarted things several times.

Comment: In which line you will get NPE?

Comment: You should have your `ViewPager` hold `Fragment`s as its views instead.

Comment: @subodh edited question to show it easier

Comment: @AlexLockwood could you explain that more?

Comment: @jjcard see my answer it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

update your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method as below, It may help you

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter= new ViewPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
        pager.setCurrentItem(1);

        // added by subodh 
        TextView txtView1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player1name));
        TextView txtView2 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player2name));
        TextView txtView3 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1wins));
        TextView txtView4 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2wins));
        TextView txtView5 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player1life));
        TextView txtView6 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player2life));

        setSettings(txtView1,txtView2,txtView3,txtView4,txtView5,txtView6);

    }
```

**Edit your second method:**

```
public void setSettings(TextView txtView1,TextView txtView2,TextView txtView3,TextView txtView4,TextView txtView5,TextView txtView6) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 0);
        newGame = settings.getBoolean("newGame", true);
        autoDecide = settings.getBoolean("autoDecide", true);
        saved = settings.getBoolean("saved", false);

        if (saved) {
            player1 = readPlayer("Player 1");
            player2 = readPlayer("Player 2");
            if (player1 != null && player2 != null) 
            {
                txtView1.setText("" + player1.name);
                txtView2.setText("" + player2.name);
                txtView3.setText("" + player1.totalWins);
                txtView4.setText("" + player2.totalWins);
                txtView5.setText("" + player1.life);
                txtView6.setText("" + player2.life);


            }

        }

}
```

Comment: OK, I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work. Thank you for the answer though, I thought it would work.

Comment: oh, sorry. Yes I get the same nullPointerException I got before.

Comment: With your idea:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity.setSettings(Life_counterActivity.java:95)
at jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity.onCreate(Life_counterActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)

Comment: original (line difference because I just commented out my old stuff:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity.setSettings(Life_counterActivity.java:101)
at jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity.onCreate(Life_counterActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)